# My airlock keeps becoming empty on one side, is that normal?

Tags: water, airlock

This is my first time brewing and I only started yesterday, so I'm still very much a novice.

I have a bubbler airlock on my 33 litre fermenting bucket, like the one in this image:
[image: Bubbler Airlock]

I filled it up to about 50% at each side and left the bucket overnight, when I checked it around 7 hours later, it had become empty on one side (right side if that matters). I filled it back up to 50% each side and went off to work, when I checked it just now (10 hours later), it's the same as it was this morning, 50% full on the left side and empty on the right side. I'm currently brewing 20 litres (40 pints) of cider and the temperate in the cupboard is around 18c - 20c, fairly consistently.

Is this how the airlock should function? Am I suppose to leave one side empty and have the other half full? Or do I need to keep topping it up with water every 6-8 hours or so?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Carl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Totally normal.  C02 is SLOWLY pushing the water to the opposite side of the lock.  As fermentation starts to *really* kick in, you'll see much more movement and "bubbling" in the airlock.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to keep topping up with water. As long as there is some water inside the airlock, there is a barrier to the outside environment allowing the generated carbon dioxide to escape but not allowing unwanted air in.